# Convert Date Format/Encrypt Date

Tags: winforms, vb.net-2010

I new to VB.NET coding. I have one question, kindly answer this.

I made a program which inserts *current date* into database. But when it displays the date, its format is `dd/MM/yyyy` ie. `01/01/2018`. I want the date to display as `A/A/BJAH` where *1=A 2=B 3=C 4=D etc*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i said in the comment, you would have to convert `numbers` into `alphabets`. This is a simple function to achieve what you are looking for:

```
Function EncryptDate(Datevalue As String) As String
  Dim str As String = Datevalue
  str = str.Replace(1, "A")
  str = str.Replace(2, "B")
  str = str.Replace(3, "C")
  str = str.Replace(4, "D")
  str = str.Replace(5, "E")
  str = str.Replace(6, "F")
  str = str.Replace(7, "G")
  str = str.Replace(8, "H")
  str = str.Replace(9, "I")
  str = str.Replace(0, "J")
  Return str
End Function
```

Thus `MessageBox.Show(EncryptDate(Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")))` will give

> BI/JH/BJAG